# Cannot find symbol error when trying to use my own method

Tags: java, object, methods

I have a `Time` class which has a comparison method called lessThan

```java
public boolean lessThan(Time t1, Time t2) {
    if (t1.getHours() > t2.getHours()) {
        return false;
    } else if (t1.getHours() == t2.getHours()) {
        if (t1.getMinutes() >= t2.getMinutes()) {
            return true;
        } else
            return true;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

I want to use this method inside my main class to compare to Time objects passed to sort my Time objects.

```java
public static void sortAppointments(ArrayList < Time > appointments) {
    Time val;
    for (int i = 0; i < appointments.size(); i++) {
        if (!lessThan(appointments.get(i), appointments.get(i + 1))) {
            val = appointments.get(i + 1);
            appointments.set(i + 1, appointments.get(i));
            appointments.set(i, val);
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a cannot find symbol error when I compile. What am I doing wrong? How can I use my own method inside main class?

Comment: You probably want to learn about what `static` keyword means before writing more code in Java.

Comment: In addition, I recomend you to always use curly brackets with if-else statements. Although Java allows syntax without curly brackets for one-line statements, it leads to logical mistakes that are difficult to find.

Comment: Where are you seeing the error, and what *exactly* is the error? (Which symbol can't it find?) (I suspect it's `lessThan`, but it's worth getting in the habit of *always* specifying the exact error and where it's showing.)

Comment: This is the exact error message `error: cannot find symbol
if( !lessThan( appointments.get( i ), appointments.get( i + 1 ) ) ) { `

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, you might want to read up on [Apple's notorious "goto fail" bug](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/).  Although that involved C rather than Java code, the principle is the same.  Consistently using curly braces around `if`, `else`, and loop-body blocks is a good stylistic practice for guarding against making such errors.  Personally, I make an exception only for `if` statements that are the (whole) body of an `else` statement.

Comment: Particularly relevant in Java context, albeit less so now than it used to be, is that [the original Sun coding conventions for Java](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) (dating from 1997) specify the same practice of always use curly braces for `if` and `else` bodies, excepting when the body of an `else` consists only of an `if` statement.  They describe omission of the braces as "error-prone".

Comment: Regarding your Time class, could make you comparisons easier if you had a `totalMinutes` field of `hours*60 + minutes`.  In fact, you could implement the `Comparable<Time>` interface and only reference that field and the field would not necessarily be visible to users of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write,

> I have a Time class which has a comparison method called lessThan

and

> I want to use this method inside my main class

, where apparently you attempt to realize the latter with

> ```
>             if( !lessThan( appointments.get( i ), appointments.get( i + 1 ) ) ) {
> ```

But that invocation of `lessThan()`, appearing as it does in a static method of the main class, will resolve method name `lessThan` against the main class.  The method you want is not there, but rather in the `Time` class.

Moreover, you have implemented `Time.lessThan(Time, Time)` as an *instance* method, so it needs to be invoked on an instance of `Time`, yet it does not appear to make any use of that instance.  It would make more sense as an instance method of class `Time` if it accepted only one argument, and evaluated whether the instance it is invoked on is less than the argument.  As it presently stands, the method would be more useful if it were static.

The smallest set of changes that would resolve this issue would be to

1. Make the method `static`:

   ```
   // In class Time
   public static boolean lessThan( Time t1, Time t2 ) { // ...
   ```

   AND
2. invoke it as such in your main class:

   ```
          if( !Time.lessThan( appointments.get( i ), appointments.get( i + 1 ) ) ) {
   ```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was confused about.

Answer (score 0):

Either make your method a `static` helper function and call it in a static fashion or change the signature of your method to utilise the instance of `Time` that the method exists in using `this` i.e.

```
 public boolean lessThan( Time other ) {
    if (this.getHours() > other.getHours()) {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

then utilise the instance method in your test class

```
boolean less = appointments.get(i).lessThan(appointments.get( i + 1 ));
```

Also for sorting a list, an easier way is to make your `Time` implement `Comparable<Time>` and then use `Collections.sort(list)`

Comment: Why should helper functions inside main class be static?

Comment: You said your `lessThan` method is in the `Time` class in the question

Comment: You can ignore what I said before, I was thinking about something else and didn't actually want to write that. What I want to ask is, I get why your implementation works, but don't understand what is the issue with my implementation and why java gives cannot find symbol error for lessThan method?

Comment: The fact you're getting a `cannot find symbol` suggests that `sortAppointments()` is in a different class to the method `lessThan` which is in `Time`... If they were in the same class you'd get a `cannot be referenced from a static context` message... so you're trying to access the method `lessThan` in `Time` from a method outside of `Time`. Let's say your `sortAppointments` method is in `MyClass` then calling `lessThan` is like doing this: `MyClass.lessThan` but `lessThan` doesn't exist in `MyClass` hence the `cannot find symbol` - does this make sense?

Comment: When you write only `methodName(arguments);` it means that either you are calling it on current instance, which means that it is equivalent of `this.methodName(arguments);` or that you want to call it on class itself (in case of `static` method) so it would be equivalent of `ClasName.methodName(arguments);`. Since inside `static` method "*there is no `this`*" compiler can only assume that you meant `YourClass.lessThan(...)` but to be able to call `lessThan` on class it needs to be `static`.

Comment: Yes. But now I'm more confused. Why `appointments.get(i).lessThan(appointments.get(i+1));` works despite being in another class than lessThan method but `lessThan( appointments.get(i), appointments.get(i+1)`?

Comment: Because the method `lessThan` exists in `Time` and you're calling it on an INSTANCE of time.
`Time time = appointments.get(i);`
`Time other = appointments.get(i + 1);`
`boolean less = time.lessThan(other);`

... You're accessing `lessThan` through a `Time` instance which is where the method exists (and because the method is public but ignore that for now until you can understand the basics)

Comment: @aebosnak `appointments.get(i).lessThan(...)` works because you are specifying on which instance it should be called - here the one returned by `appointments.get(i)`. It can be accessed in other classes because its visibility is specified as `public`.

Comment: Ok, I guess I got it, thank you.